# Dockerized Django and React app returning "undefined" when accessed from a different computer

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, nginx, axios

I'm developing a web application where the backend is powered by Django and the frontend is a React application. The communication between the frontend and backend is done using Axios for HTTP requests. The entire application is dockerized and it's supposed to be accessible from different machines.

When I access the application on the local machine `(http://127.0.0.1:60)`, everything works as expected. However, when I try to access it from a different machine in the same network using the server's IP address `(http://192.168.1.53:60)`, the Django backend returns `undefined` for the '/bucket-size/' endpoint.

**The button click event in my React component sends a GET request to the Django backend:**

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  axios
    .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/bucket-size/")
    .then((response) => {
      const size = response.data.bucketsize;
      const unit = response.data.unit;
      setOutput(size + " " + unit);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
};
```

**This is my docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./data:/app/data  # Added this line to persist SQLite database file
  
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 60:60
  
  nginx_backend_server:
    build: ./nginx_backend_server
    ports:
        - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
        - backend
```

**This is my nginx.config file --**

```
server {
    listen       ${PORT:-60};
    server_name  _;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $$uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

**This is my nginx.conf file --**

server {

```
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

I want to deploy the docker in a hosting provider, that will allow me to use an IP, that could access the backend data from anywhere in the world. How do i do this?

Comment: I'd recommend using a single Nginx reverse proxy for both components, using path-based routing.  If you do that then your front-end can call `axios.get('/api/bucket-size/')` without knowing a specific IP address; the relative URL should be interpreted using the URL of the main Web page.

Comment: @DavidMaze i did use this but now im getting an Axios error stating -- `message
: 
"Request failed with status code 404"`